# Spring WS client handling HTML instead of SOAP Fault

Tags: spring, web-services, soap, spring-ws, apache-commons-httpclient

I have a SOAP client that is calling many different web services.  In some cases some send back HTML error pages with HTTP error status codes instead of SOAP faults.  I know that they should be sending SOAP faults, but I want to be able to handle this scenario.  I'd like to be able to get access to the HTML error page.  Right now when I get back an HTML error page with a 200 status code, a SoapMessageCreationException is thrown, which I catch.  HTML error pages with HTTP error status codes throw WebServiceTransportException.  How can I access the HTML data in the response at that point? I am using org.springframework.ws.transport.http.CommonsHttpMessageSender (Jakarta Commons HttpClient) as the message sender, with Spring 2.0.

I would like the code to be able to work with the default message sender if possible, otherwise, I would just check whether the instance of the message sender is CommonsHttpMessageSender  or not.  I prefer not to have to upgrade to Spring-WS 3/Apache HttpComponents right now, but am open to it if necessary.  If I call this.webserviceTemplate.getMessageSenders(), is it ok to always take the first one ([0])?

```
try {    
    this.webserviceTemplate.sendSourceAndReceiveToResult(source,
            new WebServiceMessageCallback() {
                @Override
                public void doWithMessage(WebServiceMessage message)
                        throws IOException, TransformerException {
                    if (LOG.isDebugEnabled()) {
                        // log the SOAP request
                        ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                        message.writeTo(out);
                        LOG.debug("SOAP Request Payload: " + new String(out.toByteArray()));
                    }

                    if (soapActionHttpHeader != null) {
                        ((SoapMessage)message).setSoapAction(soapActionHttpHeader);
                        LOG.debug("Setting SOAP Action HTTP header to: " + soapActionHttpHeader);
                    }
                    else
                        LOG.debug("SOAP Action HTTP not set in the configuration.");
                }
            }, result);
}
    catch (SoapMessageCreationException e) 
{//org.springframework.ws.transport.http.CommonsHttpMessageSender
        String errorMsg= "Error processing SOAP message";
        LOG.info(errorMsg);
        LOG.debug("Stack trace: ",e);
        throw new ServiceInvocationException(errorMsg);
    }
    catch (WebServiceTransportException e) {
        String errorMsg= "Error invoking SOAP service";
        LOG.info(errorMsg);
        LOG.debug("Stack trace: ",e);
        throw e;
    }
    catch (WebServiceIOException e) {
        throw new ServiceInvocationException(e);
    }
```

Comment: Hi, could you find a solution for it? have the same problem but no solution.. thanks!

Comment: @Ludwig, No unfortunately I didn't find a solution.  Maybe there is none and it's better to switch to a different library.